# Error trying to use admob for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm a begginer, let me start by saying that. I have just downloaded `admob's SDK` and I get this error:

```
duplicate symbol _main in:
    /Users/xcodeclub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cuarto_Rey_Gratis-crbrvlfyuitkjkdlkfzjeumldcau/Build/Intermediates/Cuarto Rey Gratis.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cuarto Rey Gratis.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-B9843B6026D6EFA4.o
    /Users/xcodeclub/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cuarto_Rey_Gratis-crbrvlfyuitkjkdlkfzjeumldcau/Build/Intermediates/Cuarto Rey Gratis.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cuarto Rey Gratis.build/Objects-normal/i386/main-A2D5DEFEFE933899.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem few days ago. Problem has been, that after adding 3rd party files into my project (not admob), I had 4 methods called "main". I have just commented 3 of them out and keeped only those one, I have in file "main.m". This solved my problem.

Comment: thank you, I have 2 main.m files, one from my project and one from admob. Could you tell me what to do? (I'm a real begginer)

Comment: I am not very experienced in this kind of problems, but I believe, that removing of admob main.m from project should fix the problem, becouse this file should not be needed now. But better back up project before doing that.